# "Regarding" field missing in emails from CRM to Outlook

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a workflow that sends emails to users and has the "Regarding" field populated with the related record. This appears fine in CRM but when the email arrives to the user in Outlook the regarding field is nowhere to be seen, even with the plugin installed.

How do I make this show up?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an email which has left Crm, gone over the net and then come back to the users mailbox?

Comment: Yeah, this is one thats gone through the email router and to the users exchange inbox

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings:
Administration > System Settings > Email tab > Set tracking options for e-mails between CRM users

It sounds like you have this set to track the email as two activities, so the sender has an email tracked with the regarding set by your workflow and this will be an "outgoing" activity", and the recipient has their own copy which is an "incoming" activity, and not the same CRM record.

If you do an advanced find of recent Email messages (eg created on = today) and add the column for "direction", sort emails by date created you should be able to spot these pairs.

This setting is needed if your security roles only allow users to see their own activities otherwise they would only ever see the ones they send, not ones they have received. Otherwise, I find it unhelpful and would always track as a single activity by unchecking this box.

Answer (score 0):

I settled for the 'background track' setting in the Client Diagnostics of the Outlook Client. I don't consider it perfect - however it populates the 'regarding' entity on every Sync with the server, which is defaulted to 15 mins.